# how do I enable emacs cursor scroll with mouse wheel in Urxvt terminal?

Tags: emacs, scroll, terminal

mouse-wheel-mode is enabled however the cursor does not scroll as it had in other terminal emulators, on other distros. I've done a lot of digging and cant seem to find the answer.

Comment: Does it scroll in other text editors, such as vim?

Comment: You might take a look to see which escape sequence (if any...) emacs sends to initialize the mouse-mode.  I would capture output from running emacs with `script` and make that in visible form with [`map`](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:map) to see the escape sequences, referring to [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking).

Comment: I just realized this should be on SU not SO, sorry

Comment: @BrianMalehorn No it does not, it will scroll the whole window if i enable i think its something like xterm-mode for emacs, but not cursor which is what im looking for.